# A uniqueness result for the Neumann problem for the Laplace equation

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a $C^{1}$-domain, not necessarily bounded. Consider solutions $\phi : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega) \cap C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$, $\nabla\phi \in L^{2}(\Omega)$, to the Neumann problem
\begin{align}
\Delta \phi (x) &= 0 &&\text{ in } \Omega \\
\nabla_{\! n} \phi(x) &= g(x) &&\text{ in } \partial \Omega
\end{align}
I want to prove that $\nabla \phi$ is unique in this case.

The standard approach to proving this in bounded domains is to take two solutions to the above problem, say $\phi$ and $\psi$, and investigate the convergent integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla \phi - \nabla \psi \rvert^{2} \, d^{3}x.
\end{align}
Using the divergence theorem, we find that
\begin{align}
I = \int_{\partial \Omega}  (\phi - \psi) (\nabla_{\! n} \phi - \nabla_{\! n} \psi) \, d^{2}x = 0,
\end{align}
such that we must have $\nabla \phi = \nabla \psi$ in $\Omega$, and by continuity, in $\overline{\Omega}$.

Is this proof valid when $\Omega$ is unbounded?

Comment: consider the case of $\Omega= R \times (0,\pi)$ with $ \partial_\nu  \phi=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.   You can find nonzero solutions;  if you impose some bounds on the solution then you can prove $ \phi=0$ is the only solution. (I mean a constant is the only solution)

Comment: @Math604: i interpret the OP's question to be precisely whether $\nabla \phi \in L^2(\Omega)$ is a strong enough bound to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes, that is what I'm asking. When $\Omega$ is bounded, the above proof holds. When $\Omega$ is unbounded with compact boundary, then one can also apply the above reasoning by taking a sufficiently large ball, integrating, and letting the radius of the ball approach infinity. This utilizes some further results on the decay of harmonic functions. For general unbounded domains, I am however unsure how this would work.